# Creating a radio button text for a webpage

Tags: html, radio-button, form-submit

I'm trying to create a revision website for teens, and i want to implement a test using radio buttons and with a submit at the bottom which will tell them wether their answers are correct or not. The answers will all be set to be one of the 4 answers. Can anyone explain the easiest way to do this just using hard code as i am reluctant to use a database as at the moment it is just local.

Comment: Do it all with JavaScript then (albeit this won't be secure, but that's another story) - define the questions, define the answers to the questions. On submit, compare the checked set value against that answer.

Comment: It can be done with PHP as well, no database needed. The PHP file will just compare the $_POSTS to the hard coded values. The advantage if this is that the right answers will be stored in the php file and no one except you will know them.

Comment: So what do you mean, give each answer a set number e.g. a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4?

Comment: How would you do it using PHP, I've had very little experience using PHP ?

Comment: What technology is at your disposal? Does your website support PHP? Can you consider using node.js? Why your reluctance to a database?  Have you considered SQLLite? Too many questions for this question to be answered appropriately please refine / make better question.

Comment: Yes my website supports PHP, i dont know what node.js is, Well im not reluctant i just thought it may be simpiler to use hard coe, i am open to any suggestions, i just want to learn.

Comment: @user3092467 - thank you, I posted an answer that refers to just using javascript, however PHP will be the better option because that "code" is hidden from source viewing and users wont be able to just look for the answers in the code. Any number of the PHP solutions posted should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Save this in a file named quiz.html, or any name you want (just keep the .html extension), and try it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .valid{color:#1F1}
      .invalid{color:#F11}
      #overall{font-size:2em;font-weight:bold}
    </style>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="form-content"></div>
      <div><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/></div>
      <div id="overall"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Questions and answers
      // You can add questions from here >>>>>
      var questions = [
        {"question":"Question 1","possibleAnswers":{"1":"Answer 1-1", "2":"Answer 1-2", "3":"Answer 1-3","4":"Answer 1-4"},"validAnswer":"3"},
        {"question":"Question 2","possibleAnswers":{"1":"Answer 2-1", "2":"Answer 2-2", "3":"Answer 2-3","4":"Answer 2-4"},"validAnswer":"1"}
      ];
      // To here <<<<

      // Building quiz
      var form = $(".form-content");
      for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++) {
        var q = questions[i];
        var qHtml = '<div id="dq'+i+'"><div>'+q.question+'</div><div>';
        var pas = q.possibleAnswers;
        $.each(pas, function(j, val) {
          qHtml = qHtml + '<input type="radio" name="q'+i+'" value="'+j+'">'+val+'<br/>';
        });
        qHtml = qHtml + '<div class="result"></div></div>';
        form.append($(qHtml));
      }


      var overall = $('#overall');
      // Checking answers on button click
      $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
        var goodAnswers = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++) {
          var q = questions[i];
          var qDom = form.find('#dq'+i);
          var v = qDom.find('input[name="q'+i+'"]:checked').val();
          var rDom = qDom.find('.result');
          if (v == q.validAnswer) {
            rDom.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid').html('Valid answer');
            goodAnswers++;
          } else {
            rDom.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid').html('Invalid answer');
          }
        }
        overall.html('Final result: ' + goodAnswers + '&#47;' + questions.length);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's a HTML/JavaScript only webpage (not secure for somebody with JavaScript knowledges, though). Pay attention to the part that says "You can add questions from here". It's a javascript array, and you can add as many questions, with as many options as you wish. Just keep the pattern of each question element:

```
{
  "question":"Here goes the question",
  "possibleAnswers":  // List of possible answers, "value":"text" pairs, as a JSON object
    {
      "1":"Answer 1",
      "2":"Answer 2",
      "3":"Answer 3",
      ...
      "N":"Answer N"
    },
  "validAnswer":"3"  // Value of the valid answer
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Modified to use radio buttons instead of dropdown.

**EDIT 2:** Removed logging, and added overall result.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you start. Place all of the code in a file called quiz.php and try it.

HTML:

```
<html>
<form action='quiz.php' method='POST'>
<input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male<br>
<input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>   
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php      
$q1 = $_POST['sex'];
if($q1=='male')
{
echo 'correct!';
}   
?>
```

Comment: A good simple example. Perhaps form action to self and load all the code into 1 page for sake of simplicity for an OP who professes to not know what PHP is. - edit - i see you added call the file quiz.php that works too.  We're still assuming his webhost supports php at this point though.

Comment: Would the PHP file just contain that code given there? or would it have the usual

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of submitting user input and doing something with it in PHP :

HTML

```
<form action='myphpfile.php' method='POST'>

What brand has a model called Q7 ?
<select name="question1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="submit">submit</input>
</form>
```

PHP , myphpfile.php

```
<?php
$answer1 = "audi";

if($_POST['question1'] == $answer1){echo $answer1.' = is the right answer !'}
else{echo 'Wrong answer'}
?>
```

Comment: cant assume that OP has a PHP enabled website, per the question this is not explained.

Comment: I never did, just gave an example of how it could be in PHP.

Comment: I'd like to see the OP pressured in comments first, to fix his question and explain what techs are available to him before we all go throwing out answers. An answer in PHP if PHP is not available is not an answer at all.

Comment: Would the PHP file just contain the code you have put there or would it have the usual Html stuff at the beginning and end ?

Comment: the php file just that. in the html file, you do the html stuff.

Comment: Instead of file.html you name it file.php and integrate the php code in with the actual HTML, refer to PHP.net and Google for a bazillion tutorials.

Comment: When i try this, once i press submit, it goes goes to a page where it just shows the PHP code, does this mean PHP is not enabled or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Do you have it running on a (local?) web server ?

Answer (score 0):

here you go, an idea for you

```
<?php
//Set Answers//
$q1_answer = 'b';
$q2_answer = 'a';
$q3_answer = 'c';

$form = '<form action="" method="post">
Question 1<br />
A<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"/>
B<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"/>
C<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c"/><br />
Question 2<br />
A<input type="radio" name="q2" value="a"/>
B<input type="radio" name="q2" value="b"/>
C<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c"/><br />
Question 3<br />
A<input type="radio" name="q3" value="a"/>
B<input type="radio" name="q3" value="b"/>
C<input type="radio" name="q3" value="c"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>';

if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
if ($_POST['q1'] === $q1_answer){
    $q1_res = 'correct';
}else{$q1_res = 'incorrect';
    }
if ($_POST['q2'] === $q2_answer){
    $q2_res = 'correct';
}else{$q2_res = 'incorrect';
    }
if ($_POST['q3'] === $q3_answer){
    $q3_res = 'correct';
}else{$q3_res = 'incorrect';
    }
$display = 'Q1 = '.$q1_res.'<br>
            Q2 = '.$q2_res.'<br>
            Q3 = '.$q3_res.'<br>';

}else{
$display = $form;
}

echo $display;
?>
```

Comment: you forgot your leading <?php tags, this script breaks. Also why is everyone assuming the OP has PHP enabled website?

Comment: added the opening "<?php"
and lets be fair, i would say 99% of websites are php enabled

Comment: 99%? hardly, 65% at the best. PHP is typically enabled for linux but not for windows IIS servers and the OP specifically states that this is "local" and asks about "hard code" which I can only assume is HTML and that he in fact has no webserver installed at all.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP - "As of January 2013, PHP was installed on more than 240 million websites (39% of those sampled) and 2.1 million web servers"   WOW - in fact my 65% estimate is way off the actual count according to wikipedia. not even 40%

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain the easiest way to do this just using hard code as i am reluctant to use a database as at the moment it is just local.

Your solution is to use Javascript and do your best to obfuscate the answer file. Since your question does not tell use if you have PHP or another server solution like node.js available we have to assume that HTML/Javascript is all that is at your disposal.

StackOverflow usually advises against external links as answers but I'm providing these here as support links to check out.

https://github.com/jrue/JavaScript-Quiz

http://uhaweb.hartford.edu/kelley/quiz/quizmaker-gen.html

Fundamentally, using the github example you create a quiz file in javascript, personally unlike the github example I'd put this in its own .js file and link it instead of including in the HTML header.  I'd also obfuscate the .js file as to disguise the potential answers to source code snoopers, there are plenty of tools available to do this online.

Ultimately a PHP or Node.js solution will be your best choice for a secure test if you have those available.  Please consider revising your question to help us answer it better.